# Search vendors by checkbox and select options

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database, search

I have a list of vendors like this (as picture bellow)

[image]

http://www.pkbazaar.com/classifieds-house-real-state-sale-buy-lahore-karachi.php

## Now can I want to **search vendors** by "service provided", "Budget" and "star rating"?

I am using **search query** like this

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT vendor.* FROM vendor
LEFT JOIN  items_ratings ON vendor.vendor_id=items_ratings.vender_id
LEFT JOIN  services ON vendor.vendor_id=services.vender_id
WHERE vendor.price >= ".$_POST['priceA']." AND vendor.price <= ".$_POST['priceB']." AND (SELECT AVG( items_ratings.rating )
FROM `items_ratings`
WHERE vendor.vendor_id = items_ratings.vender_id
AND (SELECT service_name
FROM `services`
WHERE vendor.vendor_id = services.vender_id
AND vendor.vendor_type = '".trim($_POST['vendor_type'])."') >= ".$_POST['rating']." AND vendor.vendor_type= '".trim($_POST['vendor_type'])." AND services.vendor_type= '".trim($_POST['service_name'])."' GROUP BY vendor.vendor_id");
```

and my other code is like this

**JS code**

```
function search_func()
{
var priceA = $('select#valueA').val();
var priceB = $('select#valueB').val();
var guestA = $('select#g_valueA').val();
var guestB = $('select#g_valueB').val();
var rating = $('select#rating').val();
var facility = $('#service_name').val();
var vander_type = $('#vander_type').val();
var dataString = 'priceA='+priceA+'&priceB='+priceB+'&rating='+rating+'&service_name='+facilities+'&vendor_type='+vander_type;

$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "ajax_pages.php?act=get_list",
          data: dataString,
          success: function(response) { $('#listing_div').html(response); }

     });
}
</script>
```

I amd using **PHP** with **mysql database**
..............................................................

**Note:** Search by budget and star rating are working properly when I remove this code from query `LEFT JOIN  services ON vendor.vendor_id=services.vender_id`
and

```
FROM items_ratings
WHERE vendor.vendor_id = items_ratings.vender_id
AND (SELECT service_name
FROM `services`
```

and remove this code from JS

```
var service_name = $('#service_name').val();
```

and

```
'&service_name='+service_name+
```

Comment: Your sql query seems wrong! Learn it first

Comment: first thing that comes to my mind is that $('#service_name').val() is possible problem. Have you try to print it?

Comment: and for SQL you can easily check that query by putting some random values to see if it works.

Comment: alright, do you have any question ?

Comment: Unrelated, but important: you seem to be using unfiltered `$_POST` data in your SQL query. This is **really insecure**! Please take a moment to read about [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: I read about SQL injection but my problem is not related to SQL injection